# Adicionar controles desde evento AJAX en .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Les comento, tengo una vista que inicialmente se muestra con unos controles fijos, y dependiendo de la opción que el usuario escoja, en la misma vista debo agregar otros controles que obtendre de la BD.

Para esto estoy realizando un llamado Ajax cuando el usuario selecciona un valor en un campo autocomplete de la vista, con el siguiente script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#codigo_tipo_credito").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'AutocompletarTipoCredito',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                data: request,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item + ""
                        }
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#codigo_tipo_credito').val(ui.item.label);

            var partes = ui.item.label.split("-");

            if (partes.length > 0) {
                var idTipoCredito = partes[0].trim();
                if ($.isNumeric(idTipoCredito)) {
                    ObtenerCampos(idTipoCredito);
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
                else {
                    alert("El valor seleccionado en el campo Tipo credito no es correcto.")
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("El valor seleccionado en el campo Tipo credito no es correcto.")
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Este Script invoca a un método en mi controller llamado "*ObtenerCampos*", que es el método que va a la BD y obtiene la data con la cual voy a pintar los nuevos controles. El consumo del método por Ajax no tiene ningún problema, va hasta BD, recupera la data, la pongo en el *Viewbag*, y es aquí donde tengo problemas.

Ya que tengo la data en el *Viewbag*, pero la vista no se actualiza y entonces no hace en a vista lo que quiero que haga, mostrar los campos dinámicos que obtuve de la BD.

En el script agregue la línea `window.location.reload(true);` para obligar a recargar la pagina, y efectivamente me recarga la pagina pero el valor del *Viewbag* se pierde.

Les agradezco cualquier orientación que me puedan brindar.

Mil gracias.

Comment: Y el controlador devuelve una vista completa o solo el html con los controles a mostrar?

Comment: devuelve la vista completa. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Una opción es que el controlador devuelva un JSON con la información de los controles a mostrar y luego desde el cliente agregarlos usando javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Porqué lo que veo necesitas cambiar tu estructura de ajax, ya que con Net Core funciona diferente.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'AutocompletarTipoCredito', // Url
            data: JSON.stringify({
                param1: "value1", // Parámetros
                param2: "value2",
                // ...
            }),
            type: "POST"  // Verbo HTTP
        })
        // Se ejecuta si todo fue bien.
        .done(function (result) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item,
                    value: item + ""
                }
            }))
        })
        // Se ejecuta si se produjo un error.
        .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {

        })
        // Hacer algo siempre, haya sido exitosa o no.
        .always(function () {

        });
```

Y como segundo comentario, qué es lo que mandas en tu controlador para saber un poco más lo que estas tratando de mostrar.

Saludos.